# How do I place all 'favorites = 1' on top in a sql query and sort return by a specific column?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to find the right query for my SQLite db which is used in my Android application. I have a db containing Notes, which has fields such as title, text, isFavorite, isTrash, creationEpoch, modifiedEpoch. What I want to do is to for example sort the db query by modifiedEpoch ASC/DESC but place all rows that are favorites on top.

I've looked at several similar questions on stackoverflow but can't get it working.

This is an example of what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM note
WHERE trash = 0
ORDER BY CASE modified_epoch WHEN favorite = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC,
         favorite DESC
```

Which places the favorites on top but not sorted by modifiedEpoch and the non-favorites seem to be sorted in ASC order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want two sort criteria:

- first sort based on isFavorite
- then on modifiedEpoch

Assuming isFavorite can be 0 or 1, this should work:

```
ORDER BY isFavorite DESC
       , modifiedEpoch DESC
```

This puts all favorits first, having the most recent ones very first followed by non favorits, again starting with the most recent ones (due to DESC on modifiedEpoch).

Comment: Thank you for the response, when I use this with ASC it places the favorites in the bottom. I wan't to always display the favorites on top.

Comment: @zet You have two independend ASC/DESC specificiations. To always have favorits top, just keep DESC on the isFavorite column.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM note 
WHERE trash = 0 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN favorite = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, modified_epoch DESC
```

favorite = 1 go first ordered by modified_epoch , all the rest favorite = 0, 2, ... follow ordered by modified_epoch

Comment: Thank you for the response, this worked perfect for me! The favorites stays on top even if I use ASC.

Comment: @zet Yes, ASC is default